# Is there anything more than `fastcheck` to speed up Unison?

Tags: unison

I routinely use Unison to sync users' home directories between workstations where the user is expected to work. Unfortunately, as the firm grows, the Unison become slower and slower in determining what files have changed. The time taken by actual transfer is negligible in comparison.

The synchronization is done in the star topology, with RAID-6 unison server in the center. Some workstations use Windows (with NTFS), some Linux with either Ext-4 or BTRFS(!).

At the time of writing, there is one user, whose home directory is 45GB large with 100K files, and the full synchronization time takes about 30 minutes for him. Note, that simple directory traversal with `find >null` takes less about 2 minutes.

What are the strategies for further speeding up the process? (except reducing the number of files to sync) I believe that in theory the Unison can be sped up, but the `fastcheck` option isn't enough.

Answer (score 5):

OK, I've found the culprit: the unison does ignore the `fastcheck` option for `xls` and `mpp` files and always performs the full comparison for them. It does so, because Excel is in habit of modifying the xls files without changing the last modified date.

Unfortunately for us, `xls` makes files about 20% of the whole volume of the documents.

Editing the `/usr/bin/unison` in hex editor and replacing `xls` for something not likely to be found (like `xxx`) did the trick.

In Unix filesystems (btrfs, ext4) this procedure should be safe, as any change of the file should change the inode number, and unison is supposed to use this information if available. As for the clients based on ntfs, I think we should suffer the slow time... or maybe there is some alternative (abandoning Excel or changing the file system).

After this hacking, the unison sped up more than ten times!

Comment: If a file was changed in-place, the inode will not change. Only if a file is replaced by a new file (as many editors do) will it get a new inode number. The file modification time will be updated on change, though.